# How prove that $AD$ and $BC$ of the given convex quadrilateral are parallel?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, alternative-proof, quadrilateral

Here is the problem:

> In the convex quadrilateral $ABCD$, it is known that $AD > BC$, points $E$ and $F$ are the midpoints of the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$, respectively, $EF = \frac{1}{2}(AD - BC)$. Prove that AD ∥ BC.

I thought that I'd proven it, but after a short review I understood that my proof is not correct. That's the short beginning that I think might lead to the whole solution:

1. Let $K$ be the midpoint of the segment $AB$, draw the $KF$ line segment, $KF \cap AC = X$. So $KF$ is the midline of the $\triangle ABD$.
2. Since $(EF = \frac{1}{2}(AD - BC))$ => $(AD = BC + 2EF)$ => $(KF = KX + XF = \frac{1}{2}BC + EF)$.

And now I'm stunned a bit, because intuitively it's clear that the points $E$ and $X$ are both the midpoints of the segment $AC$, which would help to prove what's asked, but I'm not sure how to prove it. How to do that? Alternative proofs are very welcome.

[image]

**Please, note that this problem is only from an 8th grade school textbook and the answer must be within the given topic, which is simply "Midline of a triangle"**.

Comment: Use `$\implies$` for $\implies$.

Comment: Better yet, write it out in English.

Comment: @Shaun, okay, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K$ be the midpoint of $AB$, as in your attempt.

Consider $\triangle ABD$, then $KF = \frac12 AD$.

Consider $\triangle ABC$, then $KE = \frac12 BC$.

Verify that $KE + EF = KF$, so $KEF$ is a straight line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How does it come to be true: "$KE + EF = KF$, so $KEF$ is a straight line." ?

Comment: @curioushuman If $K,E,F$ instead form a triangle, then instead $KE + EF > KF$.

Comment: I complicated everything, the proof were right in front of me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea. However, instead of introducing $X$, just draw from $E$ to the midpoint of $AB$, i.e., your $K$. Since by SAS we have $\triangle AEK \sim \triangle ACB$, we then get

$$\lvert KE\rvert = \frac{1}{2}\lvert BC\rvert \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Similarly, $\triangle BKF \sim \triangle BAD$ so

$$\lvert KF\rvert = \frac{1}{2}\lvert AD\rvert \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Using what's given, as well as \eqref{eq1A} and \eqref{eq2A}, we have

$$\lvert KE\rvert + \lvert EF\rvert = \frac{1}{2}\lvert BC\rvert + \frac{1}{2}(\lvert AD\rvert - \lvert BC\rvert) = \frac{1}{2}\lvert AD\rvert = \lvert KF\rvert \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This shows that $KEF$ is a straight line. From the triangle similarity conditions (e.g., $\measuredangle AKE = \measuredangle ABC$ and $\measuredangle AEK = \measuredangle ACB$), we get $KE \parallel BC$ and $EF \parallel AD$. Thus, this means that

$$AD \parallel BC \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Comment: Similarity of triangles will be introduced several topics further in the book, so I can't really use it to solve this problem. The answer of @peterwhy is the simplest here and correct, so I accepted his answer as the best for my case. But I upvoted your answer as well. Thanks!

Comment: @curioushuman You're welcome, and thanks for the info. However, the fact that $\lvert KE\rvert = \frac{1}{2}\lvert BC\rvert$ and $\lvert KF\rvert = \frac{1}{2}\lvert AD\rvert$ is, at least, closely associated with the triangles being similar. Out of curiosity, how otherwise can you know that's true, e.g., was it just stated as a theorem without any proof, another method was used (e.g., sums of vectors), etc.?